# Web Essentials Nightly 2.2.4 can not compile Sass because it can not find module 'node-sass'

Tags: visual-studio-2013, sass, web-essentials

My scss won't compile in VS2013. The node-sass folder exists at the same level as the node-sass-middleware folder and has the node-sass module in it. Has anyone else seen this error?  Do I need a new version of node?  Does that node-sass module need to be copied somewhere else?

```
Error   11  module.js:340
throw err;
      ^
Error: Cannot find module 'node-sass'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:280:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
    at require (module.js:380:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\chris\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\12.0\Extensions\yiqxufal.vun\Resources\nodejs\tools\node_modules\node-sass-middleware\middleware.js:1:74)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)        1   1
```

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed this by install the `node-sass` module using `npm`

```
npm install -g node-sass
```

and then I copied the module into web essentials directory - from `C:\Users\me\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\node-sass` to `C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\12.0\Extensions\[something]\Resources\nodejs\tools\node_modules\node-sass`.

Comment: Unfortunately this did not work for me.  I also tried the same with the node-sass-middleware folder.  Finally, I uninstalled and reinstalled web essentials 2.2, and even though there is now an error with no error information, the scss compiles.